# Is it possible to filter a text file for Real numbers using grep function?

Tags: perl, unix

I am trying to filter a text file for the lines in the file which begin with a certain number or less than that specific number.
Is it possible to achieve this using the grep function?

I tried to write a Perl script to do this and I downloaded the module for capturing Real numbers, but it doesn't seem to work.
Here was my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common qw /number/;

    while (<>) {
        /^$RE{num}{int}$/                and  print "Integer\n";
        /^$RE{num}{real}$/               and  print "Real\n";
        /^$RE{num}{real}{-base => 16}$/  and  print "Hexadecimal real\n";
    }

print "Enter limit: ";
chomp( my $limit = <STDIN> );
$limit = abs($limit);

open my $IN, '<', "xt_spacer_results.hairpin" or die $!;
open my $SIFTED, '>', "new_xt_spacer_results.hairpin" or die $!;

   while (<$IN>){
        next if /^None/;
        next if /^($RE{num}{real}{-places=>2})/ && $1 <= $limit;
    print $SIFTED $_;
    }

close $IN;
close $SIFTED;
```

**Edit: The format of the text file is:**

Sequence ID

(Energy value) 7-spaces (start_pos) 2-dots 6-spaces (end_pos) 3-spaces (left-flank-seq) spaces (palindrome-seq-spaces) (right-flank-seq)

```
>hsa_circ_0067224|chr3:128345575-128345675-|NM_002950|RPN1  FORWARD
(-4.4)       (6) ..      (17)   (xxxxxxxxxxGTGAC)                (CAGT ATGC ACTG)                 
(AAGATGAGGTTTGTG)
-0.9       5 ..      18   xxxxxxxxxxxGTGA               CCAGT ATGC ACTGA                
AGATGAGGTTTGTGG
None       3 ..      22   xxxxxxxxxxxxxGT             GACCAGTATGCACTGAAGAT              
GAGGTTTGTGGACCA
-2.3       5 ..      26   xxxxxxxxxxxGTGA           C CAGTATGCACTGAAGATGAG G            
TTTGTGGACCATGTG
-3.2       4 ..      27   xxxxxxxxxxxxGTG          AC CAGTATGCACTGAAGATGAG GT           TTGTGGACCATGTGT
-1.9       3 ..      28   xxxxxxxxxxxxxGT         GAC CAGTATGCACTGAAGATGAG GTT          TGTGGACCATGTGTT
```

So my script is supposed to filter out all energy levels which are 'None', as well as all energy levels which are less than the value which the user input.
Using the example above if the user entered the value -2 then the following would be the result of filtration:

```
>hsa_circ_0067224|chr3:128345575-128345675-|NM_002950|RPN1  FORWARD
-4.4       6 ..      17   xxxxxxxxxxGTGAC                CAGT ATGC ACTG                 
AAGATGAGGTTTGTG
-2.3       5 ..      26   xxxxxxxxxxxGTGA           C CAGTATGCACTGAAGATGAG G            
TTTGTGGACCATGTG
-3.2       4 ..      27   xxxxxxxxxxxxGTG          AC CAGTATGCACTGAAGATGAG GT           TTGTGGACCATGTGT
```

All 'None' is removed along with -1.9 and -0.9 as these are not low enough.

Comment: Please post some sample data also, along with expected output.

Comment: Just saying "It doesn't work" doesn't give us enough to work with - describe in detail what isn't working and what you expect it to do.

Comment: The `while (<>)` loop in the beginning takes all STDIN that you type at a keyboard. Once you exit that (Ctrl-C or so) the program quits so you never get to the main part. Comment out (or remove) that whole `while (<>) {...}` and it works. Or use the simpler approach in the answer by Dave Sherohman.

Comment: The data has spaces, I don't know how to incorporate that.When I paste it in it looks like a jumbled mess. I will give it a try though...

Comment: >hsa_circ_0067224|chr3:128345575-128345675-|NM_002950|RPN1  FORWARD
-4.4       6 ..      17   xxxxxxxxxxGTGAC                CAGT ATGC ACTG                 AAGATGAGGTTTGTG
-0.9       5 ..      18   xxxxxxxxxxxGTGA               CCAGT ATGC ACTGA                AGATGAGGTTTGTGG
None       1 ..      20   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             GTGACCAGTATGCACTGAAG              ATGAGGTTTGTGGAC
None       2 ..      21   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxG             TGACCAGTATGCACTGAAGA              TGAGGTTTGTGGACC
None       3 ..      22   xxxxxxxxxxxxxGT             GACCAGTATGCACTGAAGAT              GAGGTTTGTGGACCA

Comment: If you edit the question and paste the data in as a code section (the same as your Perl code), the line breaks should be preserved instead of it turning into a mess. If you also update the question with your desired output, I can modify the example code in my answer to work properly with your actual data format.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Getting used to Stack, I'll get there soon. Apologies for late reply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The Perl `grep` function can filter based on any arbitrary conditional, not just regexes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

my @lines = <DATA>;

my @small_numbers = grep { looks_like_number($_) && $_ < 3.1416 } @lines;

print for @small_numbers;

__DATA__
Foo
17
1.387531
0
2
3 and a bit
```

Output:

```
1.387531
0
2
```

`Scalar::Util` and `looks_like_number` can be omitted if you're confident that your data will be strictly numeric, of course, but the code included in the question implies that you have at least one possible non-numeric value ("None").

Comment: (Not that it matters at all, but they want to keep the numbers greater than..)

Comment: @zdim - I went by the English description of their intent and completely missed that the code does the opposite. Ah, well. I'll leave it as-is because, as you said, it doesn't affect the answer in any substantive way.

Comment: Yes, it tripped me, too -- I only realized when I checked (that it is only that first `while` in) their code, with your data (thank you :).  That's the only reason I commented, just to inform. I wouldn't change this good answer either.  Btw, I really like the "_3 and a bit_" for this purpose :)